# Error with TfidfVectorizer and SelectKBest

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to follow this tutorial for doing some sentiment analysis, and I'm pretty sure my code is exactly the same up to this point. However, I'm getting a critical difference in values for my BOW.

https://www.tensorscience.com/nlp/sentiment-analysis-tutorial-in-python-classifying-reviews-on-movies-and-products

Here's my code up until this point.

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2


def openFile(path):
    #param path: path/to/file.ext (str)
    #Returns contents of file (str)
    with open(path) as file:
        data = file.read()
    return data

imdb_data = openFile('C:/Users/Flengo/Desktop/sentiment/data/imdb_labelled.txt')
amzn_data = openFile('C:/Users/Flengo/Desktop/sentiment/data/amazon_cells_labelled.txt')
yelp_data = openFile('C:/Users/Flengo/Desktop/sentiment/data/yelp_labelled.txt')


datasets = [imdb_data, amzn_data, yelp_data]

combined_dataset = []
# separate samples from each other
for dataset in datasets:
    combined_dataset.extend(dataset.split('\n'))

# separate each label from each sample
dataset = [sample.split('\t') for sample in combined_dataset]


df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, columns=['Reviews', 'Labels'])
df = df[df["Labels"].notnull()]
df = df.sample(frac=1)


labels = df['Labels']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=15)
bow = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Reviews'])
len(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

selected_features = SelectKBest(chi2, k=200).fit(bow, labels).get_support(indices=True)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=15, vocabulary=selected_features)
bow = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Reviews'])

bow
```

Here's my result.

[image: My result]

This is the result from the tutorial.
[image: Problematic part in tutorial]

I've been trying to figure out what could be the issue but I haven't gotten anything going yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're supplying indices, try instead suplying a real vocab.

Try this:

```
selected_features = SelectKBest(chi2, k=200).fit(bow, labels).get_support(indices=True)
vocabulary = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())[selected_features]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=15, vocabulary=vocabulary) # you need to supply a real vocab here

bow = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Reviews'])
bow
<3000x200 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 12916 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```